# How to store each individual day inside time period into array

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry if title was a bit obscure, I'll give my best to explain my problem. I run query like this:

```
$queryForDateClicks="SELECT `time_send` FROM `notifications` WHERE `app_id`='$appId' AND `time_send`>'2016-04-11 23:59:59'";
```

On table like this:

[image]

So, what I need to achieve is to have all `time_send` values within one day into one array, so if date is `2016-04-12` to have array like this:

```
Array ( [2016-04-12] => 2016-04-12 07:45:37, 2016-04-12 08:07:03, 2016-04-12 08:13:48)
```

And if time interval for witch I need to store those dates is let's say from `2016-04-05` to `2016-04-12` array would look like this:

```
Array ( [2016-04-05] => 2016-04-05 06:45:37, 2016-04-05 11:17:30, [2016-04-06] => 2016-04-06 02:35:37, 2016-04-06 23:17:30, [2016-04-07] => 2016-04-07 06:45:37, 2016-04-07 21:17:30)
```

And so on for each different day inside given time interval. So I tried doing it like this:

```
$queryForDateClicks="SELECT `time_send` FROM `notifications` WHERE `app_id`='$appId' AND `time_send`>'2016-04-11 23:59:59'";
    $chartResultDate=$mysqli->query($queryForDateClicks);
    $dani=array();
    while($brojDate=$chartResultDate->fetch_assoc()){
        $minutes = substr($brojDate['time_send'], -8);
        $days = substr($brojDate['time_send'], 0, 10);
        if($minutes< '23:59:59'){
        $dani[$days]=$brojDate['time_send'];
    }else{
        //should increment day by one and start checking again if minutes for that day are less than '23:59:59' and so on.
        }
    }
    print_r($dani);
```

But this now prints only the last date and it's time:

```
Array ( [2016-04-12] => 2016-04-12 08:40:02 )
```

And my database stores more results for `2016-04-12` day.
[image]

Please help me with this, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query could look something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(time_send) as time_send_date, time_send
FROM notifications
WHERE time_send > '2016-04-11 23:59:59'
ORDER BY time_send
```

To build such an array you need, you can use this part:

```
$notificationDataArray = [];
foreach($datalist as $row){
    if(!array_key_exists($row['time_send_date'], $notificationDataArray)){
        $notificationDataArray[$row['time_send_date']] = [];
    }
    array_push($notificationDataArray[$row['time_send_date']], $row['time_send']);
}
```

Please note that `$datalist` is the array of data from the database.

You will then have an array like this:

```
array (size=2)
  '2016-04-11' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '2016-04-11 13:52:23' (length=19)
      1 => string '2016-04-11 14:45:57' (length=19)
      2 => string '2016-04-11 15:41:21' (length=19)
  '2016-04-12' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2016-04-12 11:21:29' (length=19)
      1 => string '2016-04-12 18:45:30' (length=19)
```

Comment: Great job dude. Thanks :)